# SSRS End Users Custom Report

Tags: reporting-services

I am new to SSRS and I am teaching myself SSRS but I'd like to know if it is possible to create a report with SSRS that let end users (who have no skills in SQL) can generate a report on their own on GUI by selecting multiple datasources, multiple tables and columns?
What I currently have in mind that I could throw in a bunch of parameter but i don't think it is efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Included with SSRS is a feature called [Report Builder](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff660783) that basically does what you're suggesting. It uses an Office-style Ribbon interface to make building reports fairly straightforward for non-technical users.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. I will research more into that.